# CombineLatest in Combine is not fired

Tags: swift, combine, combinelatest

```swift
let a = Just("a")
let b = Just("b")
_ = Publishers.CombineLatest(a, b).map { a, b in
    print(a, b)
}
```

This is my simple `CombineLatest` test. I am calling this method in `onAppear` function. 
However, my `print(a,b)` is not called. How should I fix my code to run `print(a, b)` ?

Comment: You need to call `sink`

Comment: It would be good to start from Apple's [Introducing Combine](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/722/) and *Related videos* on same page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Publisher` doesn't produce values until it is given a `Subscriber`. The `map` operator isn't a `Subscriber`.

The easiest solution (as mentioned by Sajjon) is to use `sink`:

```
let a = Just("a")
let b = Just("b")
_ = Publishers.CombineLatest(a, b).sink { a, b in
    print(a, b)
}
```

Please note that `sink` returns an `AnyCancellable`, and when that `AnyCancellable` is destroyed, it cancels the subscription. In this example, the `_ =` means I'm not saving that `AnyCancellable`, so it is destroyed immediately. That doesn't matter here, because all of the `Publisher`s in this example (the two `Just`s and the `CombineLatest`) operate synchronously. They have published everything they will ever publish before the `AnyCancellable` is destroyed. But in general, you need to save the `AnyCancellable` if you're subscribing to a `Publisher` that can publish values asynchronously.